# Sums of squares of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

> **Question:** What is the least number that is a sum of three squares of primes in exactly six ways?

... I know it is not research mathematics. Happy new year!

EDIT: Now that it is answered I should note that I learned this puzzle from a tweet by [Ed Southall](https://twitter.com/solvemymaths). I thought it is fun to share.

Comment: If you know it is not research mathematics, why post it here? [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) exists.

Comment: this is more like a puzzle, right? the answer is 2019 $$2019=a^2+b^2+c^2,\;\;\text{with}\;\;(a,b,c)\in\{(7,11,43),(7,17,41),(13,13,41),(11,23,37),(17,19,37),(23,23,31)\}$$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, you are right.

Comment: Is there an elegant or intuitive solution? Of course, one can easily find the answer with a computer program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is 2019

$$2019=a^2+b^2+c^2,\;\;\text{with}\;\;(a,b,c)\in\{(7,11,43),(7,17,41),(13,13,41),(11,23,37),(17,19,37),(23,23,31)\}.$$

I think this was first noticed by [Ed Southall](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2018/dec/31/can-you-solve-it-2019-in-numbers)

Answer (score 6):

The sequence $f(n)$ given by those smallest integers which can be written in $n$ ways as the sum of squares of three primes has first eleven values,

$$12,219,363,699,1179,2019,2259,3891,4059,6459,5379.$$

As one can see, the $10$th value, $6459$, is larger than the $11$th value, $5379$. This is [OEIS A214512](https://oeis.org/A214512), which indicates that it was *really* T.D. Noe  who observed this earlier.

In any case it will be some time before this puzzle can be used like this again.